# Why does MySQL LEFT JOIN not return all rows unless there is WHERE clause - phpMyAdmin issue

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Consider the following:

eventTypes table has 163 rows.

events has 43,000 rows.

```
SELECT events.eventTypeID, eventTypes.eventTypeName 
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN eventTypes ON events.eventTypeID = eventTypes.eventTypeID
```

This returns 163 rows. However, if I add "WHERE events.eventID >= 0"

```
SELECT events.eventTypeID, eventTypes.eventTypeName 
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN eventTypes ON events.eventTypeID = eventTypes.eventTypeID 
WHERE events.eventID >= 0
```

I get all 43,000 rows. I would expect the lack of a WHERE clause would give me everything. Am I thinking about this wrong?

Update: I just tried this on another server and same result. My exact query copied and pasted is:

```
SELECT events.eventTypeID, eventTypes.eventTypeName FROM events LEFT JOIN eventTypes ON events.eventTypeID = eventTypes.eventTypeID
```

This only returns the first 163 records. MySQL Versions are 5.5.29 and 5.1.61. I looked in the bug list and found nothing.

Update #2: EXPLAIN gives the same output with either query (i.e. with or without WHERE 1=1)

```
mysql> EXPLAIN(SELECT events.eventTypeID, eventTypes.eventTypeName FROM events LEFT JOIN eventTypes ON events.eventTypeID = eventTypes.eventTypeID);
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                           | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events     | index  | NULL          | eventTypeID | 4       | NULL                          | 37748 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eventTypes | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | casefriend.events.eventTypeID |     1 |             |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Update#3 Testing on a 3rd system produces results I expect though I have no idea why. The 3rd system is another CentOS6 running MySQL 5.1.69. I imported the exact dumps from my development system that I imported into the 2nd test system that did not produce the correct results.

#### Update#4 Found the issue. This is NOT a MySQL issue. This is a phpMyAdmin issue. When testing on the command line with mysql client I get the correct results on all systems.

Comment: What does `WHERE 1=1` give? :)

Comment: Something is wrong with your queries.  You cannot add a `where` clause and get more rows.

Comment: @hobbs WHERE 1=1 works also.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Linoff I agree but you are looking at the exact queries. I promise whats happening is true.

Comment: @TimDuncklee well I have no idea, but at least that's another data point.

Comment: @hobbs I just tried WHERE 1. Oddly that does not work (i.e. only returns 163 rows). I also tried changing the engine from InnoDB to MyISAM. No difference.

Comment: Your _second_ query is the one producing correct results - that's a `LEFT JOIN` you're using after all.  My guess is that something about the tables/indices is causing the optimizer to act funny (ie, consider as an `INNER JOIN` instead).  Your `WHERE` clause is thus making the optimizer realize "dude, he really meant this".  So it's not that the `WHERE` clause is giving you more results, it's that something about the situation is giving you _fewer_ results for some reason.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse INNER JOIN still only gives me 163 records. I suspect you are correct about the optimizer. I will try this structure and data on a 3rd server.

Comment: Get the output from an EXPLAIN  ( `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` ) on both queries. I've not encountered this issue on MySQL before; but I have had this kind of issue on Oracle, where a full table scan was encountering corruption (a spurious high water mark), but adding a hint, to get the optimizer to use the index, I could get all the rows. No errors returned. What's odd with your case is that the number of rows being returned matches the number of rows in one of the tables.

Comment: Can you repeat the test, but use a tablename other than `events`? (Just wondering if there's code in the optimizer for special handling of the information_schema.events table; anything else odd about the tables (blob, text, etc., character keys, mismatched collations... consider supplying the output from a `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: @spencer7593 I just added the EXPLAIN to my question. Do you mean change the table name and try it again? I do not have another existing table with the same data. If you are wondering if the is an issue with other LEFT JOINS, no. I do a lot of MySQL and have never experienced this. I worked at this for many hours with much frustration because I KNEW my queries were correct. I do these in my sleep... LOL

Comment: It would have helped a lot if you had mentioned phpmyadmin to begin with.

Comment: @JimGarrison You are correct. I should have thought of that. :(

Comment: The first query should basically return all records in events table and   matches in eventsTypes..this should be 63000.                          The >=0 condition in second query implies that you return all records in events table that match records in eventType table...should rfeturn 163

Comment: Check for stable version on php-myadmin. I use PMA quite often(eventhoug i prefer cli) and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this at SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9908b/1

```
create table event (id int,type_id int);
create table type (type_id int, type_name varchar(30));

insert into type values(1, 'type 1');
insert into type values(2, 'type 2');
insert into type values(3, 'type 3');
insert into type values(4, 'type 4');
insert into type values(5, 'type 5');

insert into event values( 1,1);
insert into event values( 2,1);
insert into event values( 3,1);
insert into event values( 4,1);
insert into event values( 5,2);
insert into event values( 6,2);
insert into event values( 7,2);
insert into event values( 8,2);
insert into event values( 9,3);
insert into event values(10,3);
insert into event values(11,3);
insert into event values(12,3);
insert into event values(13,4);
insert into event values(14,4);
insert into event values(15,4);
insert into event values(16,4);
insert into event values(17,5);
insert into event values(18,5);
insert into event values(19,5);
insert into event values(20,5);

select event.id, type.type_name from event left join type
on event.type_id=type.type_id
```

I get 20 rows back as expected

Comment: I loaded your code into my database and tried it and it does work for me on my system also. Now to figure out what is "special" with my situation...

Comment: What is the output on your system? If only 5 rows, WHICH 5 rows?

Comment: I did my best to copy my structure and some data to sqlfiddle and stay inside the 8000 char limit. I did manage to do a successful test and it does work correctly on sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c410/2 So, something strange on my systems. Next I try the full dataset on a 3rd server I guess.

Comment: What version of MySQL? Linux or Windows? Can you remove and reinstall MySQL?

Comment: I have tried it with MySQL Versions 5.5.29 and 5.1.61. One on a Mac running Mountain Lion with MAMP (development system). The other is on a CentOS6 server.

Comment: Thank you for the test with 5 rows idea. This caused phpMyAdmin to show it's bug. The green results bar said 5 but I had a full 30 results on screen. All NULL. In case you missed the update, mysql client produces the correct results.

Comment: The only thing I can think of Are there any spaces on your id column. sometimes it makes a difference..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT events.eventTypeID, eventTypes.eventTypeName 
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN eventTypes ON events.eventTypeID = eventTypes.eventTypeID 
WHERE events.eventID >= 0
```

Beacuase if you mention (**events.eventID >= 0**) it means get all those rows they have this condition true and events table has 43000 rows and condition true for all rows and you using LEFT JOIN so you get 43000 rows

Answer (score 0):

```
I would expect the lack of a WHERE clause would give me everything. 
Am I thinking about this wrong?
```

Yes , you are right your first query is correct and it should return what you are expecting.
You are using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` , which means all records from left table and matching records from right table.

This is issue is not related to MYSQL version as my knowledge.

My suggestion is ,please check the relation (foreign key and primary key) on which you are joining both table.